Python async behaviour in crawler
I have a crawler code written using the Crawlee package, where users upload their website links, and the crawler scrapes all the links within the provided input. However, the issue is that Crawlee mixes the crawled links between different users' inputs, leading to shared user data.
My code:

async def run_crawler(username, urls) -> None:

    crawler = PlaywrightCrawler(
        max_requests_per_crawl=10,
        retry_on_blocked=True,
        #max_session_rotations=10,
        max_request_retries=5,
        # concurrency_settings=self.concurrency_settings,
        
    )

    crawled_data = []
    # Define the default request handler, which will be called for every request.
    @crawler.router.default_handler
    async def request_handler(context: PlaywrightCrawlingContext) -> None:
        context.log.info(f'Processing {context.request.url} ...')


        # Extract data from the page.
        try:
            text_content = await context.page.evaluate("document.querySelector('main').innerText")
        except:
            text_content = await context.page.evaluate("document.body.innerText")


        data = {
            'username': username,
            'url': context.request.url,
            'title': await context.page.title(),
            "context": text_content,
        }
        
        # Push the extracted data to the default dataset.
        await context.push_data(data)
        crawled_data.append(data)

    
        await context.enqueue_links(
            strategy =  EnqueueStrategy.SAME_DOMAIN,
        
            )

    # Run the crawler with the initial list of requests.
    await crawler.run(urls)
    await crawler.export_data(f'data/{username}_results.json')

    return crawled_data


async def run_multiple_crawlers(user_requests):
    tasks = []
    
    for username, urls in user_requests:
        tasks.append(run_crawler(username, urls))
    
    # Run all crawlers concurrently
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
    return results

# Example usage with a list of user requests
user_requests = [
    ('user1', ['https://github,com']),
    ('user2', ['https://stackoverflow.com']),
    # Add more users and URLs here
]

# Run the crawlers
asyncio.run(run_multiple_crawlers(user_requests))


This should work
async def main(domains):
    for domain in domains:
        await crawler.run(domain)
        await crawler.export_data('results.json') 
if name == 'main': 
 asyncio.run(main(['example.com', 'google.com']))

